# How to use imageData in animations

Tags: canvas, dirty-data, imagedata

I have an object that stores `imageData` with a `createImageData()` function. I do not want to create any more `imageData`s, but I want the data to be cleared each frame. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call its `.data` *Uint8ClampedArray*'s [`fill(0)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/fill) method, this will reset all the pixels to transparent black.

For better perfs, you can even create an *Uint32Array* view over this `.data`'s ArrayBuffer:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById( 'canvas' );
const ctx = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
const imgData = ctx.createImageData( 500, 500 );
for(let i=0; i<imgData.data.length*4; i++) {
  imgData.data[ i ] = Math.random() * 255; // some noise
}
ctx.putImageData( imgData, 0, 0 );
ctx.font = "30px sans-serif";
ctx.fillText( "click to clear", 30, 30 );
canvas.onclick = (evt) => {
  // clear the ImageData
  new Uint32Array( imgData.data.buffer ).fill(0);
  ctx.putImageData( imgData, 0, 0 );

};
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500" ></canvas>
```